# WSO2 IS 5.10 Self sign-up in only one form

Tags: forms, jsp, servlets, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm working on customizing the WSO2IS Self registration.

The Self registration has two parts :

- Ask the username and verify the validity and unicity.
- Ask others claims in a form

What I want is only a form with the username and the claims input.
I manage to add the username input on the second page but I want to add the username verification and to remove the first page.

When I change the web.xml it returns me that error :

ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/accountrecoveryendpoint].[register.do]} - Servlet.service() for servlet [register.do] threw exception java.lang.StackOverflowError

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Edit -My changes that works:

- I added the username field in the second part of form

  ```
                       <div class="username field">
                           <img class="mail icon-form" src="../accountrecoveryendpoint/images/mail-fill.svg">
                           <div class = "username required field">
                               <label for="username">
                                   <%=IdentityManagementEndpointUtil.i18n(recoveryResourceBundle,"Username")%>
                               </label>
                               <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="username form-control" required>
                           </div>
                       </div>
  ```

It overrides the username used for the first part and if it is not valid or unique WSO2 won't create it but the form is sent.

- In web.xml I tried to change the jsp file of the register.do servlet.

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>register.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/self-registration.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
```

But it sent error

Comment: Can you mention the changes done in jsp files and web.xml? It will be easier to provide answers

Comment: Hello Anuradha , I've mentionned the changes, thanks for your time